# Window Spread favors one screen

Tags: unity

I'm a huge fan of the Window Spread function. I have two screens though, and often a lot of windows.

When I use Window Spread, I often end up with a huge number of windows on the left screen, and only 1-2 windows on the right screen.

It's particularly noticeable when I spread windows from all workspaces, and I can end up with 20 windows on the left screen, and 2 on the right screen.

Can this be remedied in any way?